# How can I iterate through a collection of WebElements, and print to log ONLY the results that match to a substring?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to handle this case, it appears to PASS but no logs are printed...

```
it('is Substring in Results?', function() {
  this.timeout(50000);
  driver.findElements(By.xpath('.//*/div[@id="rso"]/*//div[@class="g"]'))
    .then( (elements) => {
      for(n=0; n<elements.length; n++) {
        elements[n].getText().then( (results) => {
          // print to log if matches substring
          if(results.match('Mooooooo!!!! I2MaC0W')) {
            console.log(results);
          }
        });
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `assert()` ? It won't work because you are not using assert statement.

Comment: @Sonicd300
I did used `assert.equal(results, '/Moooooo! I2MaC0W/g');`. but the Assertion returned this error log:

Comment: `AssertionError: expected 'ReconGate\nrecongate.com/\nReconGate lets you fuse diverse data sources and apply state-of-the-art machine learning in order to gain valuable insights and make the right decisions ...' to equal '/Mooooo! I2MaC0W/g'`

Comment: Assuming we changed the substring to something that actually exists in the results, like:
`'/Recongate.com/g'` , an AssertionError will be raised again with the following:




`AssertionError: expected 'ReconGate\nrecongate.com/\nReconGate lets you fuse diverse data sources and apply state-of-the-art machine learning in order to gain valuable insights and make the right decisions ...' to equal '/Recongate.com/g'`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the text check to the XPath and find only those elements that match. For example, the XPath below uses the XPath you have but adds a text check on the `DIV`.

```
'//*/div[@id="rso"]/*//div[@class="g"][.="Text to match goes here"]'
```

BTW, your XPath started with `.` but it's only needed when you are doing a relative search, which are you are not in this case. For example,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("someId")).findElement(By.xpath(".//input"));
```

In the case above, you would want the `.` since it's a chained search and you want to start with the element returned in the first search.

Comment: In that case, what is the impact on rest of the code bellow?

Comment: You would just count the number of returned elements and if the count is > 0, it passes. Ideally you would use a framework like TestNG, NUnit, etc... whatever is available for mocha to assert that the count is > 0.

Comment: I don't fully understand.. :-/
can you share in `code` alike answer of the concept?

Comment: I don't do mocha, only C# and Java. I'm sure you can google the concepts in mocha and find code samples.